# This is the query I need to convert from SQL to CodeIgniter:

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, forum

```
SELECT perusahaan.id_perusahaan, perusahaan.namaprshn, petugas.id_petugas, petugas.namaptgs, dokumen.id_dokumen, dokumen.negara_spr FROM perusahaan INNER JOIN petugas ON perusahaan.id_perusahaan=petugas.id_perusahaan INNER JOIN dokumen ON petugas.id_petugas=dokumen.id_petugas
```

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes and being put on hold as you haven't explained anything about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code:

```
$this->db->select('perusahaan.id_perusahaan, perusahaan.namaprshn, petugas.id_petugas, petugas.namaptgs, dokumen.id_dokumen, dokumen.negara_spr');    
$this->db->from('perusahaan');
$this->db->join('petugas', 'perusahaan.id_perusahaan=petugas.id_perusahaan');
$this->db->join('dokumen', 'petugas.id_petugas=dokumen.id_petugas');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Hope it helps you.